# Print the elements in an agentset

Tags: netlogo, agentset

I want to find the patches which satisfy certain conditions, using the following command:

```
print patches with [ (closest-party = turtle 1) and (distance < 10)]
```

give this as the result: (agentset, 7 patches)

how do i find those 7 patches inside that agentset

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `myset` is an agentset, then `[self] of myset` will be a list of the agents.

```
let myset patches with [ (closest-party = turtle 1) and (distance < 10)] print [self] of myset
```

But usually you can just work with `myset`.  E.g.,

```
ask myset [print self]
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Appreciate the quick response